# Create a Div with a % width but it's interior 2000px wide with overflow scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive site with a navbar at 30% and content at 70%, but inside the content I want a scrollable div that will be roughly 2000px wide [Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VflKi.png)

Okey thanks, for letting me know that i need to upload code, so the basic code i have is this

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height: 100px;width :100%; background-color: lightblue">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <!-- MENU LATERAL IZQ -->
        <div id="lateralIzq" style="height: 500px; background-color: lightgreen; width: 30%; float: left;">
            

            <!--GALLERY-->

        </div>
        <div id="Algo" style="height: 500px; background-color: lightcoral; width: 65%; float: right; overflow-x: scroll">
            <div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
            <div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
            <div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
            <div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And i would like for them to be in the same line bot to overflow to the right and be able to scroll it

Comment: Yes it is possible! What have you tried so far? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, make an effort of your own and post it properly with a working snippet and an explanation

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to add another div in the middle and  give that a static width of x and the inner divs make them float left.
The end code is the following :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height: 100px;width :100%; background-color: lightblue">
            <h1>Index</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="lateralIzq" style="height: 500px; background-color: lightgreen; width: 30%; float: left;">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="Algo" style="height: 500px; background-color: lightcoral; width: 65%; float: right; overflow-x: scroll;">
            <div style="width: 10000px;">
                <div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; display:inline; vertical-align: top; float:left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
                <div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline;vertical-align: top;float:left ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
                <div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline;vertical-align: top;float:left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
                <div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline;vertical-align: top;float:left ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```